# Do not read the file in the package .jar

Tags: java, netbeans, http-post, inputstream, netbeans-8

This code reads the firmware upgrade file from JAR package and send as Post request to device:

```
CloseableHttpClient client2 = HttpClients.createDefault();

HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://" + IP + "/moxa-cgi/UploadFirmwareFile.cgi");

InputStream stream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("vport364a_v1_5.rom");

byte b[] = new byte[stream.available()];

stream.read(b);

MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();

builder.addBinaryBody("uploadfile", b, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, "vport364a_v1_5.rom");

post.setEntity(builder.build());

HttpResponse response2 = client2.execute(post);
```

For unknown reasons, the code stopped working as execute jar package: firmware upgrade file send as nulls. On line:

```
stream.read(b);
```

only nulls already.
If I run code in IDE Netbeans, it works.Why?

Comment: Propably the file `vport364a_v1_5.rom` isn't in the jar (you should receive an IOException) or is of length zero. Check the contents of the .jar file.

Comment: No, I checked the file in the package, there is one and proper length. I haven't IOException, only nulls in POST request and device restarting(damaged file, incorrect checksum). But if I run my code in IDE, it works and firmware make upgrade.

Comment: First guess: there is something wrong with `stream.available()` if you read the stream from the jar (NB will read from the `class` folder when running and finds a normal file). Try to print to stderr  interesting values when running from jar.

Comment: Thanks, problem resolved! Instead 'Main.class.getResourceAsStream' I used 'new FileInputStream' and all works!